# how to do Serializtionf of a file

Tags: java

i have a xml file named as default xml with sample contents as

```
<check>hi</check>
```

in my application i am doing an operation such that it wil operate on the xml and writes the new value to it, by overriding the newvalue on the oldone 
ex:

```
<check>hi updated</check>
```

and i closed my application now

my problem is here:

whenever i start application again i should get the contents of default xml as

```
<check>hi<check>
```

instead of

```
<check>hi updated</check>
```

how can i achieve this ,can i have an steps to implement this r any sample code to implement this

i wil b thankful to ur valuable replies

Comment: How do you read, process and write the XML file? Please add some code snippets to make it clear what you do.

Comment: You should also put more effort into your questions, many of them are poorly formatted and/or not easy to understand

Comment: Hi there, please not that stackoverflow.com is about high quality questions and high quality answers, usable as a reference for later readers. There is no such thing as a dumb question, at least when it's posted correctly. But your question is both hard to understand AND uses incorrect spelling, case, punctuation, abbreviations... even in its title! This will turn down about 90% of the potential readers.

Comment: And of course that's just a personal opinion, but I prefer words like are, be and your over r, b and ur...

Comment: Also, don't ask for "sample code" - instead, explain the technical concept that you're having trouble grasping and ask for help understanding it so that you can write you *own* code.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think he is a native speaker.

Comment: I think posting a cut down version of your code is the way forward.

Answer (score 6):

Um... *don't* overwrite the file then? Keep the changes in memory or work on a temporary copy.

Answer (score 0):

Writing data:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/cust.xml");
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstName("John");
encoder.writeObject(p);
encoder.close();
```

Reading data:

```
FileInputStream os = new FileInputStream("C:/cust.xml");
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(os);
Person p = (Person)decoder.readObject();
decoder.close();
```

EDIT: You can also use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html) library. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/x-xstream/index.html) will you find a complete tutorial about it